# Why I got the OAuthException(Error code 803) When I post the User Location Details into Facebook wall?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am Developing Universal Windows Apps Using C# and XAML.

when I post the user Current location details into Facebook wall, at that time I got the Exception  like OAuthException shown in below image..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8fCl.png)

Regarding above Exception I wrote some line code below....

```
PropertySet parameters = new PropertySet();
parameters.Add("message", "Need Help, Am In Emergency. "+" " + "This is my current location " + geocoordinate.Point.Position.Latitude.ToString("0.00") + "," + geocoordinate.Point.Position.Longitude.ToString("0.00"));
parameters.Add("link", "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + App.pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude.ToString("0.00") + "," + App.pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude.ToString("0.00"));


// Set Graph api path

string path = "/" +App.sess.User.Name + "/feed";
FBSingleValue sval = new FBSingleValue(path, parameters, new FBJsonClassFactory(FBReturnObject.FromJson));

FBResult fbresult = await sval.PostAsync();
```

How to solve Above issue?

Comment: You can only query a user by their (numeric) ID, not by their username.